# Unable to create Spark Context (Livy) in Knime Analytics Platform

Tags: apache-spark, knime

I’m sorry if I am writing in the wrong topic, but I have the following issue:
I have created a Create Spark Context (Livy) node and I am trying to connect it to HDFS cluster managed by Cloudera.

I have made all the settings for Spark Job server and Livy URL (hope so) and when I try to execute the node, it creates a livy session (checked in YARN), it allocates the configured resources from the node, but after that I get the following error:
“ERROR Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 Execute failed: Broken pipe (Write failed) (SocketException)”

**Here are some YARN logs**:
[Yarn Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90P1t.png)

**Here are Knime Logs**:

```html
2021-12-22 18:02:49,579 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Creating new remote Spark context sparkLivy://dfe62d7e-a250-41a3-9601-1bac31379ffb at https://cm-master1-all-prod.emag.network:8998 with authentication KERBEROS.
2021-12-22 18:02:49,585 : INFO : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : SparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Spark context sparkLivy://dfe62d7e-a250-41a3-9601-1bac31379ffb changed status from CONFIGURED to OPEN
2021-12-22 18:03:21,097 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Uploading Kryo version detector job jar.
2021-12-22 18:03:21,801 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Running Kryo version detector job jar.
2021-12-22 18:03:22,400 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Using Kryo serializer version: kryo2
2021-12-22 18:03:22,400 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Uploading job jar: /var/folders/13/8vjx3pj137l2qrh_xwpnqwqc0000gp/T/sparkClasses16857522895332955503.jar
2021-12-22 18:03:22,423 : INFO : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : LivySparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Destroying Livy Spark context
2021-12-22 18:03:23,150 : INFO : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : SparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Spark context sparkLivy://dfe62d7e-a250-41a3-9601-1bac31379ffb changed status from OPEN to CONFIGURED
2021-12-22 18:03:23,151 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : reset
2021-12-22 18:03:23,151 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : SparkNodeModel : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : In reset() of SparkNodeModel. Calling deleteSparkDataObjects.
2021-12-22 18:03:23,152 : ERROR : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Execute failed: Broken pipe (Write failed) (SocketException)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.livy.context.LivySparkContext.waitForFuture(LivySparkContext.java:492)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.livy.context.LivySparkContext.uploadJobJar(LivySparkContext.java:464)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.livy.context.LivySparkContext.open(LivySparkContext.java:327)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.context.SparkContext.ensureOpened(SparkContext.java:145)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.livy.node.create.LivySparkContextCreatorNodeModel2.executeInternal(LivySparkContextCreatorNodeModel2.java:85)
at org.knime.bigdata.spark.core.node.SparkNodeModel.execute(SparkNodeModel.java:240)
at org.knime.core.node.NodeModel.executeModel(NodeModel.java:549)
at org.knime.core.node.Node.invokeFullyNodeModelExecute(Node.java:1267)
at org.knime.core.node.Node.execute(Node.java:1041)
at org.knime.core.node.workflow.NativeNodeContainer.performExecuteNode(NativeNodeContainer.java:559)
at org.knime.core.node.exec.LocalNodeExecutionJob.mainExecute(LocalNodeExecutionJob.java:95)
at org.knime.core.node.workflow.NodeExecutionJob.internalRun(NodeExecutionJob.java:201)
at org.knime.core.node.workflow.NodeExecutionJob.run(NodeExecutionJob.java:117)
at org.knime.core.util.ThreadUtils$RunnableWithContextImpl.runWithContext(ThreadUtils.java:365)
at org.knime.core.util.ThreadUtils$RunnableWithContext.run(ThreadUtils.java:219)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.knime.core.util.ThreadPool$MyFuture.run(ThreadPool.java:123)
at org.knime.core.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:246)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:121)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.LivyConnection.executeRequest(LivyConnection.java:292)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.LivyConnection.access$000(LivyConnection.java:68)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.LivyConnection$3.run(LivyConnection.java:277)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.LivyConnection.sendRequest(LivyConnection.java:274)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.LivyConnection.post(LivyConnection.java:228)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.HttpClient$3.call(HttpClient.java:256)
at org.apache.livy.client.http.HttpClient$3.call(HttpClient.java:253)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2021-12-22 18:03:23,152 : DEBUG : pool-7-thread-1 : : DestroyAndDisposeSparkContextTask : : : Destroying and disposing Spark context: sparkLivy://dfe62d7e-a250-41a3-9601-1bac31379ffb
2021-12-22 18:03:23,153 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : WorkflowManager : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 doBeforePostExecution
2021-12-22 18:03:23,154 : INFO : pool-7-thread-1 : : LivySparkContext : : : Destroying Livy Spark context
2021-12-22 18:03:23,155 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 has new state: POSTEXECUTE
2021-12-22 18:03:23,155 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : WorkflowManager : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 doAfterExecute - failure
2021-12-22 18:03:23,155 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Parquet to Spark 3:32 has new state: CONFIGURED
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Spark to Parquet 3:37 has new state: IDLE
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : reset
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : SparkNodeModel : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : In reset() of SparkNodeModel. Calling deleteSparkDataObjects.
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : clean output ports.
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : WorkflowDataRepository : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Removing handler 9c1d8004-908d-43fe-8347-45ba78bd7c58 (Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30: ) - 5 remaining
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 has new state: IDLE
2021-12-22 18:03:23,156 : DEBUG : pool-7-thread-1 : : DestroyAndDisposeSparkContextTask : : : Destroying and disposing Spark context: sparkLivy://bf46d062-17db-4ec1-8d06-28b53da7c624
2021-12-22 18:03:23,157 : INFO : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : SparkContext : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Spark context sparkLivy://f5354b5c-b44d-4460-b270-17f0ea238f4b changed status from NEW to CONFIGURED
2021-12-22 18:03:23,157 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Configure succeeded. (Create Spark Context (Livy))
2021-12-22 18:03:23,157 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 has new state: CONFIGURED
2021-12-22 18:03:23,157 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : Node : Parquet to Spark : 3:32 : Configure succeeded. (Parquet to Spark)
2021-12-22 18:03:23,157 : DEBUG : KNIME-Worker-78-Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 : : NodeContainer : Create Spark Context (Livy) : 3:30 : HDFS 3 has new state: IDLE
2021-12-22 18:03:42,421 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Spark to Parquet 3:37 (IDLE)
2021-12-22 18:03:42,424 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Parquet to Spark 3:32 (CONFIGURED)
2021-12-22 18:03:44,073 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Parquet to Spark 3:32 (CONFIGURED)
2021-12-22 18:03:44,073 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Spark to Parquet 3:37 (IDLE)
2021-12-22 18:53:19,830 : INFO : main : : SparkContext : : : Spark context jobserver://cm-master3-all-prod.emag.network:8090/knimeSparkContext changed status from NEW to CONFIGURED
2021-12-22 18:53:23,611 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Spark to Parquet 3:37 (IDLE)
2021-12-22 18:53:23,613 : DEBUG : main : : NodeContainerEditPart : : : Create Spark Context (Livy) 3:30 (CONFIGURED)
```

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Thank you in advance,
Andrei

Comment: Do your homework. A very simple Google query using the error message found in the YARN logs i.e. `IllegalArgumentException "not existed channel:"` points immediately to the **Livy code base** ==>  `RpcDispatcher` class and especially a bug fix for LIVY-735 which introduced that lame message.

Comment: Did you try to run a dummy Spark job with Livy, using the Livy REST API? If not, how can you be sure that your Livy setup just works, and that Knime is to blame?

Comment: Hello, Samson. First of all, why the hostility in your answer? We are already using Livy combined with Zeppelin and it works with no problem. My issue is that the livy session configured in Knime even if it starts with the configured resources (I can see this in our YARN), after short time it shuts down and I receive the error I mentioned above.